# Cannot Call FormatConditions.Add with type

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a quite simple FormatConditions adding programmatically...

someVar has the value 168. This code fails on the `.FormatCondtions.Add` line

```vb
Set Sheet = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
With Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("C2:C" & someVar)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlDuplicate
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 40, 80)
End With
```

I have also tried to use Selection, the Error stays the same

```vb
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("C2:C" & someVar).Select
With Selection
   'See above
End With
```

Comment: are you trying to highlight duplicate values?

Comment: @simoco yea.. Does that require more parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Set Sheet = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
With Sheet.Range("C2:C" & someVar)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 40, 80)
End With
```

Comment: worked like a charm thank you... Could you explain why it didn't work?

Comment: actually, there is a special syntax for CF *duplicate values*. When you are using `Type:=xlCellValue`, you're "working" with [this dialog box](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvlibx28vh8ruhg/123.JPG), but it doesn't provide you *unique values* option (but provide other options like *between*, *equal to* and so on)